# Wordpress: Media file URL broken due to Duplicator Plugin on localhost

Tags: wordpress, url-pattern

I have downloaded a copy of the website on my local pc using Wordpress Duplicator plugin.
Everything is working fine But images are not visible. So I checked with the URL structure and I got the problem.

URL Structure should be: localhost/sitename/wp-content/......
Actual Structure: localhost/sitename/C:/wamp64/www/sitename/wp-content/....

I have tried using many plugins for URL replacement but no luck. Is there any issue with the Duplicator Plugin??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While setting up project simply make sure, on step 3 left the path blank.

I have read this some where. Try this.